# AJAX call returns 'undefined'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, code-behind

I'm trying to send value of Date to code behind while using an ajax call but it is returning.
what am I doing wrong here

```html
 function FetchTime() {
               debugger;
               var Pt_AppDate = document.getElementById("appdate").value;
               var reqs ='{AppointmentDate: "' + Pt_AppDate + '"}';
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AppointmentForm.aspx/FetchATime",
                  data: reqs,
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: OnSuccessApptwo,
                    failure: function (response) { alert(response.d); },
                    error: function (response) { alert(response.d); }
               });

          }
```

Code Behind

```html
public void FetchATime()
          {
               conn.ConnectionString = dbObj.connString;
               conn.Open();
               string query2 = "Select Appointment_time from Appointments where convert(date, Appointment_date) < '" + AppointmentDate + "'";
               SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, conn);
               AvailableTime.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
               AvailableTime.DataTextField = "Appointment_time";
                DoctorName.DataValueField = "Symptom_id";
               AvailableTime.DataBind();
               AvailableTime.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Available Time", "0"));
               conn.Close();
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client-side code is trying to print a returned value:

```
alert(response.d)
```

but the server-side codes *doesn't return* a value:

```
public void FetchATime()
{
    //...
}
```

In order for something to be returned, you have to return something.  (Something serializable of course.)  For example:

```
public SomeType FetchATime()
{
    //...
    return someObject; // an instance of SomeType
}
```

Then in your client-side code you can access properties on that object:

```
alert(response.someProperty)
```